# How to download traces from Jaeger?

Tags: jaeger

In the Jaeger UI `http://localhost:16686/search`, there is an option to upload JSON files for traces.
I wonder can we download the traces from Jaeger itself and use them in the future for finding performance issues?

How can we do that, I see no option to download traces from Jaeger Ui.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you open an individual trace in the Jaeger UI, there is a View dropdown in the top right corner. One of the options is to view/download the given trace as a JSON file.

You can also programmatically query the Jaeger query service via JSON/Protobuf API, but those endpoints will not result in a data format that you can load back into the UI.

https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/latest/apis/#trace-retrieval-apis

Answer (score -1):

See the answer on this [jaeger issue](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/issues/1564#issuecomment-667291036), you will need to query elastic search or the source where the data is stored.

Alternatively, you should raise an issue on [jaeger-ui](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-ui/issues) detailing your case.

Comment: Not what was asked. The question was about downloading from the UI, and OP did not state they use ES.